# How to remove all occurrences of array element in nested array in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

My DataBase Structure is as following , it has only one `document` and `nested array` of `products` which consists `ref` to `product document's id`.

```
{
_id:"6371e078393a5194cc674369"
data: Array
  [0]:{
    image:
    title:
    products: Array
      [0]:product1Id
      [1]:product2Id
      [2]:product3Id
  },
  [1]:{
    image:
    title:
    products: Array
      [0]:product2Id
      [1]:product3Id
      [2]:product4Id
  },
}
```

My requirement is when I remove `product3` from the `product document` I want to delete its references too. So here i want to delete `product3Id` from the nested `array`.

Updated Document would look like:

```
{
_id:"6371e078393a5194cc674369"
data: Array
  [0]:{
    image:
    title:
    products: Array
      [0]:product1Id
      [1]:product2Id
  },
  [1]:{
    image:
    title:
    products: Array
      [0]:product2Id
      [1]:product4Id
  },
}
```

My tries:

```
result = await homeSpecialModel.updateMany(
  {
    _id: "6371e078393a5194cc674369",
  },
  // { $pull: { data: { products: { $eleMatch: new ObjectId(id) } } } } -- 1st try
  // { $pull: { "data.products": new ObjectId(id) } } -- 2nd try
);
```

Both didn't seem to work !

Comment: Is `"_id"` an ObjectId or a string?

Comment: It is the id of the main document, I have updated the question for more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `"arrayFilters"`.

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: "6371e078393a5194cc674369"
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "data.$[elem].products": ObjectId("6371e078393a5194cc67436b")
  }
},
{
  "multi": true,
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem.products": ObjectId("6371e078393a5194cc67436b")
    }
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-gqrT8Fas1Q).

Comment: can you help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74455783/mongodb-get-id-instead-of-id-when-use-aggregate