# MongoDB: get id instead of _id when use aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using aggregate to get `programs` of a `faculty`, all fine but the issue is I get `_id` of faculty where I want to get `id` as well, if I don't use aggregate I can get `id` and `_id` which is good but when aggregate can't get `id` but only `_id` is in the output

```
 await Faculty.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
      from: 'programs',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'faculty',
      as: 'programs'
    },
   },
 ]);
```

Faculty model:

```
  const facultySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      title: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
      },
  }, {
      timestamps: true
    });
    
    facultySchema.virtual('programs', {
      ref: Program.collection.collectionName,
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'faculty'
    });


    facultySchema.virtual('id').get(function () {
      return this._id.toHexString();
  });

  facultySchema.set('toJSON', {
      virtuals: true,
  });
```

Output

```
        {
            "_id": "63744bc780d90d5debcac013",
            "title": "FSSK",
            "__v": 0,
            "programs": [
            {
                "_id": "63746ebb305a351746fc7c9e",
                "title": "Communication (Doctor Of Philosophy only)",
                "faculty": "63744bc780d90d5debcac013",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "637474f3305a351746fc7d74",
                "title": "Anthropology and Sociology",
                "faculty": "63744bc780d90d5debcac013",
                "__v": 0
            },
```

Comment: Will [`Model.hydrate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-hydrate) populate the virtual fields?

Answer (score 0):

I think `toHexString()` is not supported in javascript so,i would recommend to use `toString()` function.

Comment: this is not correct nothing changed