# Mongodb Object Id

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, atlas

Sometimes MongoDB creates object id with only numeric and sometimes is alphanumeric can we add a validation pattern for objectId from MongoDB JsonSchema validation or PartialFilterExpression?
I need that object id should always pass this pattern /^(?=[a-f\d]{24}$)(\d+[a-f]|[a-f]+\d)/i for _id

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Aman to check if it exists a valid mongodb object you can test with following regex.

```
const regex = /^(?=[a-f\d]{24}$)(\d+[a-f]|[a-f]+\d)/i;
console.log(regex.test(`${mongodb_id}`)) //returns true if valid id else returns false
```

Comment: can you answer this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74455783/mongodb-get-id-instead-of-id-when-use-aggregate

Comment: @pawan we can use it but I have to restrict it on the database all object id should pass this regex and if do not pass this regex it will assign new object id to that document